# EJS variable not defined

Tags: undefined, ejs

The previous questions on this topic seem to address issues I think I have covered properly. I cannot pass through some basic data into an index.ejs on render.

app.js

```
//MONGOOSE.MODEL CONFIG
var blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   title: String,
   image: String,
   body: String,
   created: 
        {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        }
});
var Blog = mongoose.model("Blog", blogSchema);

app.get("/blogs", function(req, res){
   Blog.find({}, function(err, blogs){
       if(err){
           console.log("ERROR!");
       } else {
          res.render("index", {blogs: blogs}); 
       }
   });
});
```

index.ejs

```
<h1>Index Page</h1>

<%= blogs %>

<% blogs.forEach(function(blog){ %>
    <div>
        <h2><%= blog.title %></h2>
        <img src="<%= blog.image %>" >
        <span> <%=blog.created %></span>
        <p> <%= Blog.body %> </p>
    </div>
<% }); %>
```

I get the following error message within the browser:

```
ReferenceError: /home/ubuntu/workspace/RESTfulBlogApp/views/index.ejs:3
    1| <h1>Index Page</h1>
    2| 
 >> 3| <%= blogs %>
    4| 
    5| <% blogs.forEach(function(blog){ %>
    6|     <div>

blogs is not defined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/RESTfulBlogApp/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:549:12), <anonymous>:11:26)
    at returnedFn (/home/ubuntu/workspace/RESTfulBlogApp/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:580:17)
    at tryHandleCache (/home/ubuntu/workspace/RESTfulBlogApp/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:223:34)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/RESTfulBlogApp/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:437:10)
    at View.render (/home/ubuntu/workspace/RESTfulBlogApp/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:127:8)
    at tryRender (/home/ubuntu/workspace/RESTfulBlogApp/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
    at EventEmitter.render (/home/ubuntu/workspace/RESTfulBlogApp/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/home/ubuntu/workspace/RESTfulBlogApp/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:971:7)
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/RESTfulBlogApp/app.js:34:8
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/RESTfulBlogApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/ubuntu/workspace/RESTfulBlogApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/ubuntu/workspace/RESTfulBlogApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/RESTfulBlogApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/RESTfulBlogApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/ubuntu/workspace/RESTfulBlogApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/ubuntu/workspace/RESTfulBlogApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
```

A basic display of 'blogs', or the forEach loop returns the same error.

As far as I can tell, I have the correct versions of mongoose, express and ejs installed, required etc. I can check the database within the console and there is some test data there for rendering.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: before this line res.render("index", {blogs: blogs});  can you try logging blogs data and see whether or not it has the data what you are expecting?

Comment: Spent some time looking at the code again after express re-install didn't change a dime. I tried inserting a few console.logs into the code to see what functions were running - the problem was that my code contained another GET route that was meant to simply redirect to the /blogs route. I had typed res.render("index); without specifying what data to render so the ejs returned an error. I literally cannot believe I managed to debug that, or that I missed it so many times with my so-called 'fine tooth comb'!

Comment: Thanks @karthikdivi

Answer (score 2):

Spent some time looking at the code again after express re-install didn't change a dime. I tried inserting a few console.logs into the code to see what functions were running - the problem was that my code contained another GET route that was meant to simply redirect to the /blogs route. I had typed `res.render("index);` without specifying what data to render so the ejs returned an error. I literally cannot believe I managed to debug that, or that I missed it so many times with my so-called 'fine tooth comb'!